# 適切な質問かの討議：クイズ形式の質問

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方

[「Prologでは再帰的に処理する方法と、findallでリストを生成する方法があると聞きました。findallの使い方を教えてください」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2119/prolog%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E5%86%8D%E5%B8%B0%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AB%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%A8-findall%E3%81%A7%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E7%94%9F%E6%88%90%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E8%81%9E%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F-findall%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9%E3%82%92%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84)の質問は、質問者が回答を知っていてクイズ的な意図で出している気がします（コード内のコメントから推測）。  
CodeIQ的な使い方なのかも知れませんが、このような質問はスタックオーバーフローでは適切と考えますか。それとも不適切と考えますか。  
個人的にはクイズであることを明示していればありかなとは思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ヘルプによると自分の質問に回答することが積極的に推奨されているので、自分の知識をほかの人と共有する方法として問題ないと私は考えます ([自分の質問に回答できますか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer))。リンク先の創業者の[ブログ記事](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/)を読むと、ウィキやブログのような使い方が想定されています。

もし、自分の質問に回答できないとすると、知識をもっている人がかぎられるコミュニティの黎明期において、質問する人がいないから、回答ができず、知識を広めることができないという鶏と卵のジレンマに悩まされることになります。

なので、ほかの方がおっしゃるように、より適切な質問文に改善することに議論を絞ることに賛成です。

この議論の背景にある学力や学びとは何かについてもコメントしておきます。

質問者が回答を知っていたとしても、論点を絞ったり、よりわかりやすい説明、実装や理論の説明を付け加えるなど、ほかの人が協働できる余地はたくさんあります。近年、日本の学校教育は社会構成主義にシフトして、従来の知識の獲得から、集団での合意形成や意味を探ることなどに関心が移り変わっています。文科省のサイトでは「学び合い」、「協働学習」といったキーワードが使われています。

ベテランの方が基本問題に取り組む動機として、ほかの人のフィードバックをもとに自分の常識を見直し、新しいことを模索するためということも挙げられます。このような営みは「学びほぐし」や「アンラーニング」(unlearning)と呼ばれます。

社会構成主義、学びほぐしなどについて解説した本の例として「まなびほぐしとワークショップ」のシリーズを挙げます。

Comment: ご意見ありがとうございます。現状、質問文を適切にすれば問題なしというご意見が多いので、その形にしたいと思います。

Answer (score 8):

どうでしょうね、ツイッターでフォローされましたがどうやらベテランの方のようなので、
知っていても不思議はなさそうですが、あのfindallの使い方は王道でもなさそうなので
普通に質問だったんじゃないかと思います。

prologって事実を定義してprologに推測させるような動きみたいなので、
書き方って相当あると思うんですよね。

再帰の例として貼り付けたのは手ごろな問題集かなにかから貼り付けただけなんじゃないでしょうか。

---

本題として、仮にタイトルが質問風で実はクイズでしたー。というのであればちょっと気分悪いですね。

文章なおせ～MD調べろーって要求していた手前、回答できないかprolog調べたりしたので時間返してと思ってしまうかも。
今回はprolog触ってみるきっかけを得られたってことで良しとしますが。

かりにタイトルがクイズ風であっても、ブログを読みに来ているわけではないのでクイズなら他所でどうぞと思います。
その人の考えとあっていたからなんなんでしょうか？レピュテーションもクイズ王の目安？って思っちゃいますし。

---

### 追記

古いログ漁ってみたら、ツイッターで書いてましたね。findallで乱数リスト。

```
?- length(L,100),findall(R,(member(_,L),R is random(100)),_乱数リスト).

?- findall(R,(between(1,100,_),R is random(100)),_乱数リスト).
```

だそうです。

うーん、そうか。そんなのなら他の質問に時間を当てたかった。

### 追記２

私の回答者経験（ここ以外）から言えば、「こういうのはどうですか」と回答を提示して
「それは知っていますが違うやり方を探しています」と言われたとき、最初からその情報も共有してほしいと
思います。
（その点については指摘しますが、改善されないとその人に回答するのをやめようと思うことも。）

クイズ形式とわかりにくい、クイズの場合は似たような感覚に陥りますね。
なので、「自己回答する」とか、「自分は答えを知っている」とかは明示してほしいです。
そういう場合には「どういう意図でその質問を投稿した」かもあるとわかりやすいですね。

（某所の様に自作自演が頻出したらいやですけどね（そこは公式にやっちゃってましたが）。利用者がやる分にはコミュニティの責任ですから問題に感じたらそこから改善すればいいんですかね。）

編集によって対応するにしても、真意がわからなければ対応しにくいようにも思います。

想像で編集すれば間違った方向に編集してしまうケースもありますし、
声に出せない質問者であれば、質問者は「意図が変わったけどこのサイトはそういうものなんだ」と思い、編集者は「やはりあっていた」と思う。

まずはなるべく真意を共有する方向にもっていけるといいですね。

Comment: 少し様子を見てあまりにクイズ的な質問が続くようでしたら対応を考えるという形にしたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

英語版での信用度が多少ある方からの質問です。
回答を知っている可能性もありますが、日本語利用者に知られていないのなら、質問として十分に成り立っています。

投稿者は後継者育成のためもしくは、過去自分が悩んだ問題で質問をしているために、回答を知っており、クイズ形式になったと推測されます。

回答を知っているまたは、それに準ずる経験/知識がある ために、クイズ形式になってしまったものは、目的をはっきりとさせ理解者バッジを持っていなければ、投稿者自身に編集させる必要があると思います。
こちらでも文法の改善するのことも可能ですが、自身での編集の割に改善が見込まれなかった場合が適していると思います。

過去には、自分自身で回答を得ている例も多く存在しますので、やはり表現のみが不適切と考えるのが妥当だと思われます。

> [Prologでは再帰的に処理する方法と、findallでリストを生成する方法があると聞きました。findallの使い方を教えてください。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2119/prolog%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E5%86%8D%E5%B8%B0%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AB%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%A8-findall%E3%81%A7%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E7%94%9F%E6%88%90%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E8%81%9E%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F-findall%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9%E3%82%92%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84)

の例では、**なぜ、「再帰的に処理する方法」が示されたのかが不鮮明**なものとなっています。

> Prologでfindallを使ってリ‌​ストを生成する方法

や

> Prologでfindallを使ってリストを生成する方法を教えてください

などの表現が簡潔/丁寧な表現だと思われます。

Comment: 編集で出来るだけ対応していくというのは確かに良い気がしますね。