# 「探索アルゴリズムの比較」という質問は「質問の範囲が広すぎる」か？

Tags: 討議

[探索アルゴリズムの比較](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/6844/33)という質問は現在「質問の範囲が広すぎる」という理由で「改善待ち」となっていますが、この判断は適切でしょうか？

お題としては面白い質問だと個人的には思いますが、ヘルプの[「どのような質問は避けるべきですか？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)に書かれている「自分が直面している実際の問題に基づいて、実用的で回答可能な質問のみをしてください」という所からは外れているかもしれません。

例えば「XXXを実現しようとしているが、このようなケースではどの探索アルゴリズムを選択するのが良いでしょうか？」的な質問であれば、質問の範囲が広すぎるということはない気がします。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

アルゴリズムの特徴というのはアルゴリズムそのものとセットの知識です。

この質問を見たときにまず考えたのは「アルゴリズムそのものについての知識はあるのだろうか」ということです。

アルゴリズムそのものについて知っているのであれば特徴についても知っているはずです。その上で問うている「利点と欠点」とはなんなのか不明です。アルゴリズムには絶対的な利点や欠点はありません。アルゴリズムが持つ特徴が適用対象と環境に応じて利点になったりも欠点になったりもします。状況次第でいくらでも利点や欠点は考えられるので、「考えられる回答が多すぎる」質問と言えます。

逆に、アルゴリズムそのものについて知らないのであれば、特徴だけを回答するのは無意味です。この場合、アルゴリズムそのものについての説明からしなければなりませんが、この説明が長文になるのは明らかです。例えば私の手元にある書籍では経路探索で50ページほどの分量になります。

したがって、どちらにせよ適切な質問とは思えないのでクローズ票にしました。

### コメントで改善を促すという選択肢について

この質問に関していえば質問があまりにも抽象的なため、改善を提案するにしても具体的な指摘をするのは不可能で、意図を尋ねるか曖昧な指摘をするコメントにならざるを得ません。それを経て回答できる程度に具体的にするためには長大なディスカッションを要するであろうことが容易に想像されました。誰かが代表でやるならともかく実際には思い思いにいろいろなコメントがつくことでしょう。また、質問者の想定通りではない回答が投稿されることもあるはずです。それらについてばらばらにディスカッションしても全体としてはノイズの塊ができるだけです。

なお、一般論であれば、私はコメントで改善を促すことで改善できるのであればクローズ票ではなくそうすべきと考えます。

Comment: *アルゴリズムには絶対的な利点や欠点はありません。アルゴリズムが持つ特徴が適用対象と環境に応じて利点になったりも欠点になったりもします。* この文は矛盾していませんか？

Comment: この回答に賛成で、質問者はもう少し具体的な前提条件を閲覧者に示した方が良いと考えました。
どういう問題を抱えているかが具体的にわかれば、自ずと回答の範囲も狭まります。何につけても与えられている情報が少ないため、質問が広いという印象を受けるのだと思います。

Comment: @3100 この質問では最低限度のような情報が公表されるべきとお考えですか？

Comment: *「利点と欠点」とはなんなのか不明です。* 　*適用対象と環境に応じて利点になったりも欠点になったりもします。* どのような環境でどのような利点が生まれるのかそれを問うているのです。 *「考えられる回答が多すぎる」質問と* としていますが、実際、[類似画像検索への応用を目的とした階層化属性付きグラフマッチングの高速化](http://agora.ex.nii.ac.jp/~kitamoto/research/publications/kt:miru96.pdf)の3ページにおいて環境の本質を見抜き表としてまとめられています。それでいても考えられる環境回答が多すぎると言えますか？

Comment: この質問をするに至った文脈や背景がわかるような情報が質問文内にあると、とても良いと思います。

Comment: @3100 質問背景描きましたよ質問に至る経緯も

Comment: @natsukitinyak 別にあなたの身の上話が聞きたかったわけではないと思いますよ

Comment: @pgrho それ以外にプログラムや実験データを提示する必要があるのならどのような協力でもしますよ

Answer (score 4):

一言に探索と言っても探索対象は色々なものが考えられます。まともな評価関数が無く「最良優先探索」が出来ないかもしれませんし、最大深さが無制限で「深さ優先探索」が無意味であるかもしれません。**もし特定のテーマを設定せずに一般論を求めているのであれば**(太字追記)、そういった考慮を丸投げするのは努力不足ととられても仕方ないでしょうし、一般論をかいつまんで回答しても後の閲覧者の利益にもならないと思います。

---

質問の意図が説明されたので追記

経路探索がテーマということですが私は最善手探索やツリーインデックスの話かという印象を受けていました。この回答の3文目もそうですが、書き手が思っているほど明示されていない前提条件は読み手に共有されません。

またリンク先の研究では「深さ優先探索」はそもそも適さない手法であったと結論されています。これはエディットグラフについてほとんど経験のない私でも自明だと思われる記述ですが、質問にはこういった各アルゴリズムと適用対象についての考慮が伺われる部分がなく、単に概説を求めているように感じられました。

Comment: ということは、表１は正しいものではない？

Comment: @natsukitinyak 違います。本文を読んで表1が何処から参照されているのか文脈を確認してみて下さい。

Comment: 私は、このまとめられた表1が回答として欲しかった。[*質問する人がいないから、回答ができず、知識を広めることができないという鶏と卵のジレンマに悩まされ…*](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1499/4410)

Comment: @natsukitinyak 件の表も*探索*一般に対する回答になるかと言うと前提条件が色々あるように思われます

Comment: 前提条件の存在に気が付きませんでした。　質問文にどのような条件を加えたら良いですか。

Comment: @natsukitinyak 「質問する人がいないから～」の回答を読んだ時にも思ったのですが、それなら自分で回答を付けてもいいのではないでしょうか。既に回答が付いていたとしても、異論があればコメントや回答で書きこんでくれるかと思うのですが。

Comment: クローズ・改善待ちになると自分でも回答は付けることが出来ません。それと、他に回答できる人がいたら極力譲った方がいいのかと判断しました。もしかしたら、リンクの回答よりもより優れた回答をもらえるかもしれないため。

Comment: @natsukitinyak メタのコメント欄で技術的な話を続けてもしょうがないので、この回答内にも表1と矛盾する例がある、とだけ。私は基本的にsuzukisさんと同意見です。

Comment: 矛盾する例 投稿したら回答可能ですか？

Comment: *経路探索*と*最善手探索*、利用用途により名前は違いますが結局のところアルゴリズムとしては同じでは？　*ツリーインデックス*　アルゴリズムでなくデータ構造では？

Comment: @natsukitinyak 最初から適用対象(≒データの性質)についてしか問題視していません

Comment: @pgrho プログラムも追加しましたデータの性質がわかるかと思います

Comment: 「丸投げするのは努力不足」だけを注意してください。「努力」は判断しにくいです。たまに良い質問は努力不足ですが、質問としていいです。たまに初心者が相当努力をかけた上で何もできない質問になります。質問者の努力を集中するより、質問の質がもっといい判断基準になると思います。（回答全体は賛成ですが、「努力」と言う言葉だけは怖いです）

Answer (score 1):

利点と欠点が分かれば、こちらで自由にアルゴリズムを選択出来ると考えて質問しました。
あくまでも判断材料としての回答がほしいので、直面している問題は直接的には記載されていません。
回答も各々の利点欠点で６つほどを期待したものです。

どの程度から質問の範囲は広くなりますか

参考
[質問の仕方が良いとは言い難い質問への回答はどうしたら良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1678/%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AE%E4%BB%95%E6%96%B9%E3%81%8C%E8%89%AF%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E8%A8%80%E3%81%84%E9%9B%A3%E3%81%84%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E8%89%AF%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)
[「Xの一覧が知りたい」という質問の傾向と他サイトでの対応](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1381/x%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7%E3%81%8C%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%8A%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AE%E5%82%BE%E5%90%91%E3%81%A8%E4%BB%96%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E5%AF%BE%E5%BF%9C)

---

@pgrho 勉強不足・努力不足ですみませんでした。
動機が「他の人に ______ を説明してほしい」系の質問で以下を回答として認識していたのですが、無意味と仰られるのでしたら、これも模範回答として最良ではないということでしょうね。

> [表 1: 代表的な探索アルゴリズムの比較。最短経路を求める問題の場合](http://agora.ex.nii.ac.jp/~kitamoto/research/publications/kt:miru96.pdf)
>   北本 朝展, 高木 幹雄, 類似画像検索への応用を目的とした階層化属性付きグラフマッチングの高速化, 画像の認識・理解シンポジウム(MIRU’96), 1996 年7 月

参考
[適切な質問かの討議：クイズ形式の質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1489/%E9%81%A9%E5%88%87%E3%81%AA%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%8E%E8%AD%B0-%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA%E5%BD%A2%E5%BC%8F%E3%81%AE%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F)

---

この質問の範囲が広いという根拠が今のところ示されていないような気がします。

Comment: 提示されている論文に出ている利点と欠点を説明して欲しかったということでしょうか？それであれば具体的に論文名を出して、どこがわからないか明示する方が良いと思います。

Comment: また、クイズという場合には、「最短経路を求める問題の場合」という前提は最低限必要だと思います。

Comment: @tomute むしろ最短経路以外を探す場合ってありますか

Comment: 単に探索する場合、最長経路を探す場合などが考えられます。

Comment: あなたに具体的に解決すべき問題がなくただ単にその分野の概要を知りたい場合はスタックオーバーフローは向いていません。そういう用途で一番良いのは上に上げられているような書籍です。

Comment: @tomute 多分それらは、単に探索する場合、それらはアルゴリズムとしての実装が必要がなく、最長経路を詮索する場合ループを発見すること又は、深さ幅共に全ての盤面を計算する(極論がゴールを設定しない)ことになります。なので、記述が必要か疑問です。

Comment: @ぽぽたん それには同意です。しかし、適応する問題が具体的であっても抽象的であっても、アルゴリズム自体の性質は変化しません。

Comment: 具体的な適応範囲が広く性質が変化しないのでライブラリなどのような利用法が出来るのでは？

Comment: グラフを扱う問題は仕事で頻繁に扱うので、bfsもdfsも必要に応じて何度も書いていますが、最短経路を求めることよりは一つでも条件を満足する解を見つけるってことの方が多いですね。それと、問題によって効率の良いデータ構造が違うのでむしろライブラリ化しにくく、毎度問題に合わせて書き下すことの方が多いです。なので、想定している問題は何か、どの程度の抽象度の答えが欲しいのか、くらいはあった方が答えやすいかなと思います。

Comment: @shirok 確かにこのアルゴリズムについてはグラフと木でのバージョンがあるめライブラリ化されるものではありません。しかし、どのような性質のある問題に対して有効な方法というのはあると思います。実際、[類似画像検索への応用を目的とした階層化属性付きグラフマッチングの高速化](http://agora.ex.nii.ac.jp/~kitamoto/research/publications/kt:miru96.pdf)の3ページにおいて表としてまとめることができています。
このような一般的で簡潔な回答が得たく質問したのです。

Comment: ならその例を出して頂いていればわかりすかったかと。どのくらい深く知りたいかがこちらにはわからないのです。その表は間違ってはいませんし、用語に不案内な読者に理解の指針を与えるのには役立ちますが、用語は既に知っていて具体的な問題を解くための指針を求めている人にとっては当然すぎてあまり役に立たない回答でもあります。で、その表をご存知の上で質問されているということは、もうちょっと深い回答を期待されているということですか?

Comment: @shirok すでに回答にありますが、中程の*動機が「他の人に ______ を説明してほしい」系の質問で* からがその質問の回答となります。　
もうちょっと深い部分で質問できればなのですが、表を知らない時に、プログラムをくみ、結果が出るように全パターン試して最後に表を知ったので先に表をしる機会があれば時間を無意味に浪費することはなかったなと思い質問しました。

Answer (score 1):

### 今回の対応について

- 質問の改善を促し、それまでに曖昧な回答が付くことを防ぐ
- こういう質問は認められませんよ、というアピール

「改善待ち」にはこういった要素が含まれていると思いますが、少なくとも質問者さんは満足しているようなので（そのことが最初から伝わればベストですが）、前者の必要はないと考えます。

後者については微妙なところですが・・・

> 質問の内容と、回答の品質が比例するとは限りません。本家SOをみていると、大したことがない（失礼！）質問に対して、有用かつ詳細な回答が付いているケースも見かけます。このような回答を引き出した質問には、結果的に賛成投票が集まっていきます。
>
> 引用元： [「該当分野では基礎的とされる質問への反応」への回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1596/8000)

こういうケースも考えると、現時点で回答を禁止してしまうのは時期尚早のように思います。

とはいえこの質問を見たとき、「範囲が広すぎる」と思ったわけではないものの、こういったアバウトな質問はマイナス票がつきそうだなという印象を受けました。モデレーションは基本的には多数決になってしまいますから、モデレーターに対しての印象に改善の余地はあったかもしれません。

### 質問意図が掴みづらい質問について

突然「AとBとC、それぞれの利点・欠点を教えてください」と言われても、回答に困ってしまうケースは多いかと思います。こういった質問では次のような疑問が生じます。

- 一般的な回答を期待しているのか、実は前提条件が色々あるのに説明不足なだけなのか
- 質問者がそれについてどの程度の知識があるのか（「どこから説明すればいいの？」）

特にQ&Aサイトとして見れば具体的な質問や相談が多いでしょうから、言葉足らずになっている可能性について私は強く考慮します。

この場合、どういった回答をするべきなのかがわかりません。

単純に「簡潔に最善の回答をしたいから、間違いがないようにしたい」と思うほかに、以下のような懸念もあるでしょう。

- 質問者（もしくは他のユーザー）を混乱させるだけになるのでは？
- 回答にかけた時間が無駄になるのでは？
- 実は手におえない話だったらどうしよう？
- 質問者の機嫌を損ね、場の空気を悪くしてしまうのでは？
- そして・・・「俺はこんな質問に答える気はない」

結果として「回答がつかない」という状態に陥るわけですが、そういった質問の存在やそれに対する回答を強く拒否する必要は今のところないと考えています。

クローズ票以外にもユーザーが取れる反応は色々あるのですから。

> スタックオーバーフロー的には、「コメントで改善を促す」か「そのまま放置」が良いと考えています（少なくとも私は）。
>
> 「反対票を入れる」は、本当にそこまで酷いか？は再考したうえで、それでもダメだと思ったら反対投票すればよいかと。
>
> 「回答を記載して、次回からの改善アドバイス」は、賛否が分かれる点かと思います。個人的には 技術質問に対する回答 と 人の行動に対する助言 を混ぜるのは、避けるべきと考えてます。FAQサイトとしては後者は単なるノイズですし、他サイトでたまに見られる「説教くさい」雰囲気をかもしがちです。（極端なケースでは、技術回答よりも人生訓的なノリになってしまいます）
>
> 技術的な回答のみを付ければよいと思います。どうしても言いたいことがあるなら、コメントにでも書けばよいでしょうし、それも嫌なら最初から放置すればよいという考え方です。
>
> 引用元：[「質問の仕方が良いとは言い難い質問への回答はどうしたら良いですか？」への回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1687/8000)

Comment: ご意見は良くわかり同意できる話です。ただ、本メタの投稿の議論内容は「「探索アルゴリズムの比較」という質問が「質問の範囲が広すぎる」か？」ですので、「質問意図が掴みづらい質問をクローズすべきかどうか」という議論の場合、別のメタ投稿とした方が良い気がします。

Comment: @tomute 確かにnatsukiさんがその点に疑問を呈したのがこのメタ投稿の発端ではありますが、その点を議論することが重要なのだろうか？と思いこのような意見を書いてしまいました。ただ仰る通り、ここでそのことを書いても話を広げにくいですね…。

Comment: [質問の仕方が良いとは言い難い質問への回答はどうしたら良いですか](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1687/4410)については私も回答し、最終的にはベストアンサーに賛同しています。

[Plain English explanation of Big O](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o) こういった質問もあるので探索アルゴリズムの比較というような質問でも、ある程度の知識を持ち要約が行える人物ならはっきりとした回答が可能かと考えました。
もし、*説明不足なだけ* or*葉足らずになっている可能性* については、例のように理解者によるコメントにより改善可能で、*現時点で回答を禁止してしまうのは時期尚早のように思います。* に賛成です。

Comment: @unarist 「クローズ票以外にもユーザーが取れる反応は色々ある」というのはその通りだと思いますので、元投稿のクローズに関してメタで問題提起する or 元投稿の再オープンに投票するというのは如何でしょうか？

Comment: @tomute そうですね、もう少し他にクローズされる質問が出てきたら問題提起してみようかと思います（既に最近増えてきていますが）。再オープンの投票はrepが貯まり次第考えます。

Comment: @natsukitinyak 本文でも書いていますが、回答しにくい質問であることもまた確かです。そしてそういった質問はモデレーターやコミュニティを維持しようという人の目に留まりやすいです。となると、なるべく悪い印象を持たれないように質問文を考える必要もあるのかなと思います。わかりやすい質問文は、基本的に誰のためにも役立つでしょうし。

Comment: 回答しにくいことがわかったが、あなたが何がわからないか私にはわからない。わからないことが、根本的にそのことを知らないために発生しているのだとしたらそれ以前の質問をするべきだ。

Comment: @natsukitinyak 具体的にAとBが不足しているではなく、投げっぱなし質問に見えないように質問文を考えるべきでは、という話ですが、他の方は「探索アルゴリズム」という点に絞って意見されているのでオフトピだった気もします。