# クローズ理由のまとめ

Tags: 討議, クローズ理由

> <sup>当投稿は約１年前に[meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason/215220#215220)に回答として投稿しました。適切なクローズ理由について[討議があったため](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1716/%E6%8E%A2%E7%B4%A2%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%82%BA%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AE%E6%AF%94%E8%BC%83-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AF-%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AE%E7%AF%84%E5%9B%B2%E3%81%8C%E5%BA%83%E3%81%99%E3%81%8E%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%8B)、日本語で投稿しようと思いました。</sup>

Ｑ＆Ａはパズルと同じです。

完成品をまとめるには、複数のパーツの組み合わせが必要です。

> [image: パズルの完成版]

たまに、組み合わせながら、問題にあたってしまいます。

> [image: パズル組み合わせについての良い質問]

目的と現在の問題点を説明した上で、適切な解決方法が教えられます。

> [image: パズル組み合わせについての良い回答]

#### 質問内容がはっきりしない

> 問題について具体的に説明するか、情報を追加して、聞きたいことを強調してください。 現在投稿されている内容では、あなたが聞きたいことがはっきりわかりません。質問方法ページで、この質問をより明確にするためのヘルプをお読みください。

目的を説明しないと、回答者が適切な解決方法がわからず、どうしても情報の追加が必要です。「この４ピースをどう組み合わせばいい？」

> [image: この４ピースをどう組み合わせばいい？]

#### 質問の範囲が広すぎる

> 現在の質問内容では考えられる回答が多すぎる、またはまじめに答えようとするとページ内に収まりきらない長さになってしまいます。質問を編集して具体的にすることで、答えを絞り込めるようにしてください。また、焦点を絞って長くなりすぎない回答が書けるようにしてください。

目的を説明したとしても（「２４ピースのパズルを組み合わせたい！」）、現在の問題を特的しないと回答が多すぎる・長過ぎます。

> [image: ２４ピースのパズルを組み合わせたい！]

#### 主観的な答えしか集まらない

> どんなに模範的な、百科事典レベルの答えでも、経験に基づく主観性はある程度入るものです。しかしこの質問の場合、どんな答えも個人的な意見や感想になると思われます。確かな情報ソースや専門知識と経験、事実に基づいた回答ができるような質問にしてください。

特定した問題をはっきり説明したとしても、回答が意見にしかならない質問もあります。「どっちのパズルの方が好きですか？」を聞いたら、質問がはっきりしているし、範囲がかなり絞っていますが、回答が意見のみになります（正しい回答はありません）。

> [image: どっちのパズルが好き？]

#### オフトピック

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.
>
> デバグを頼んでいる質問（なぜこのコードが実行しない？）を聞くには：　①　認めているアウトプットの説明と　②　同じ問題を再現するようなコードが必要です。問題をはっきり定義しないと将来ユーザーの支援になりません。[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)を参考してください。

英語版SOでは、このカスタムクローズ理由もあります。「このパズルはうまくいかない」と言っても、あるべき姿と再現するに必要な情報を与えないと解決できません。

> [image: このパズルはうまくいかない]

現在はこの理由を当サイトに適用していないが、必要に応じて追加することも可能です。

Comment: これは、英語版での議論の結果決まった指針かと思います。いきなり結果のみを輸入するのは強引かと思います。問題となった質問、議論の会場となったメタ質問、そして最後にまとめられ指針となったはずです。私は[このコミュニティがルールを決めるべきです。](http://goo.gl/cBf4kf)には賛成していてプログラマ自体の質が上がるブログやWikiのような利用が増えることを期待しています。

Comment: @user10972 大賛成です。これは「絶対のルール」と言うより、英語版のサイトの考え方だと思って、ここから議論すれば全然構いません。言っている通り、当コミュニティが討議した上でルールを決めたらベストだと思います。