# 英語が分かれば回答が自明かもしれない質問

Tags: 討議

今日、いくつかの質問を投げさせていただきました。
その中で、英語の壁がなければ、ほとんど回答が自明な状態にまで
来ている気がすると自分で理解できる物がありました。
( [Scalaアプリに対して、クラスの依存関係をテストする方法を教えてください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/50099/scala%e3%82%a2%e3%83%97%e3%83%aa%e3%81%ab%e5%af%be%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6-%e3%82%af%e3%83%a9%e3%82%b9%e3%81%ae%e4%be%9d%e5%ad%98%e9%96%a2%e4%bf%82%e3%82%92%e3%83%86%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95%e3%82%92%e6%95%99%e3%81%88%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84) / ここに記載した資料で、タイトルくらいまでは自分で読み取れたんですが、それ以上を読み取るのは私には難しかった。)

しかしこの状態での質問は、
もしかすると単にコミュニティに対して翻訳を依頼してしまうものになってしまう可能性があり
あまりよくないのではないか、という疑問を質問した後で持っています。

スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版コミュニティとしては、この手の質問は歓迎されることでしょうか。
それともあまり望ましくないと考えるべき(しないほうがいい)でしょうか……？

Answer (score 9, accepted):

別のメタ投稿でちょうど関連する話題が挙がっています。

[スタック・オーバーフロー 多言語版：制限なく、遅れなく、包括的なものを、あなたの母国語で](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2825/3060)

詳しくはリンク先に目を通して頂ければと思いますが、ざっくり言うと「"英語"と"英語以外"とで得られる情報の隔たりを、コミュニティの助け合いで取っ払おう」といった内容です。

---

直球で「代わりに翻訳してください！」が質問(=依頼)になっているとお互い気が引けますが、英語の資料は見つかったけど読み解く自信がない…ということであればその事実も包み隠さず記してみてください。
どこまで理解して、どこからが分からない、という部分がはっきりと書かれていれば手助けもしやすいはずです。

別の例になりますが、「こんなエラーが出ました。よろしくお願いします」といった素っ気ない質問をよく見かけます。英語のエラーを注意深く読めばヒントが書かれているのに、単に英語が読めないのか、エラーの内容を理解できないのかが第三者からは汲み取れないので、こういった質問形式だと個人的には評価が低いです。

質問する際は[まず自分で調べてみる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)ことが望ましいですが、回答を付けるかどうかは個人の判断によるところが大きいので、例え丸投げ質問だろうと回答を付けられる内容であるならサクッと回答してくれる人がいるケースもあるでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。まさにその記事を読んでいたので、質問してもよいだろうと思いました。一方で、自分で調べられるかもしれないなら、辞書などを使って、より時間を掛けて調べるのが適切かもしれないとも思いました。(ただし後者を実施した場合はQ&A形式で再投稿するなどをしないとコミュニティに還元はされない)この場合の答えとしては、おっしゃるように理念のほう(英語以外で得られる情報の隔たりを無くそう)を重視したほうが良いわけですね。ただしもうちょっと他の方の意見も聞いてみたいです。

Comment: SOにおいては「自己回答」も許容されますので、質問で回答を募りつつ、平行して自分で調べて分かったことがあればそちらも回答として載せる、と言うやり方もアリだと思います。

Answer (score 6):

個人的には、本家 SO で何が質問されてて何が回答されていようが、全部無視して質問してやるぐらいでいいのではないかな、となんとなく思います。

というのも、スタックオーバーフローにおける質問は、ある種のパズルの定式化のようなものだと思っており、それは、本来言語に依存するものではないはずだと思っているからです。 参考: [クローズ理由のまとめ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1729/754)

ここでいうパズルというのは、今の自分の理解と求める解との差分という意味であり、それは質問者の母国語が何であったとしても、質問を作成する際にはその質問者の中ですでに存在していて、言語は、それをどう表現するかの違いでしかないと考えるからです。

ただ、ここで難しいのが、プログラミングの世界においてこの界隈の標準言語は英語である、というところかと思います。例えば、公式ドキュメントや諸々の規格文書は、原文は英語であることがほとんどかと思っており、その意味で英語は避けられない性質はあるかとは思います。

しかしそれでも、冒頭のパズルとして質問を定式化しようとした場合に、例えば特定の規格の原文の意味がわからないであるとか、公式ドキュメントのここの記述が分からないであるとかならば質問としてありえるかとは思いますが、まるまるどこかの記事を翻訳してくれ、といったような質問の仕方には基本ならないのではないかと思っています。

また、例えば Qiita の記事をひたすら漁っていけば見つかったかもしれないマニアックな scala の文法についての質問は、ただそれがすでに存在したからといってここスタックオーバーフローでそのような質問が歓迎されないかと言われればそのようなことはない(と自分は思っている)のと同じように、本家SO ですでに全く同じ質問があってそれを延々と辞書片手に読み込んでいけば問題を解決できるのであったとしても、やはり冒頭のパズルの形式できちんと表現することができるのであるならば、それはスタックオーバーフローにおいて歓迎されるべき質問であると考えます。

そう考えていくと、スタックオーバーフローの質問においては、外部サイトへのリンクは質問本文に含めてもいいけれども、基本はその投稿内部で完結しているのが望ましく、また逆に、外部リンクがどうしても必要になるのは上で述べた公式ドキュメントや諸々の規格などといった、正式文書ぐらいなのではないかなと思っています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。この視点はとても大事な気がします。特に "外部サイトへのリンクは本文に含めてもいいけれど、投稿内部で完結していることが望ましい" という点です。SOにはQ&Aを構築するという発想があり、「コンテキストを外に読みに行かないと完結できないのでは、Q&Aとしては完成していない」という発想があると思いました。多言語版SOでは、特に読み手が理解できない英語ドキュメントを拾われると困るという意味で、この傾向がより顕著なのかもしれません。

Answer (score 3):

既に回答があり、一部、重複するとも思いますが、疑問があります。

まず、
 全ての質問に回答する義務があるのでしょうか? 仕事で回答されている方ならば、別かと思いますが、そうでなければ、放置してはいけませんか? 別のどなたか親切(?)な方の回答を待つべきと思います。

また、
ここで質問する人は英語で読み書きできないといけないのでしょうか? 確かに英語ができた方が色々と都合の良い事が多いのは事実ですが、質問者にそれを要求する必要があるかという事です。 もし、それを要求するならば、日本語サイトなんて不要かと思います。

[追記]
もう一つ忘れてました。
日本語で検索しても(答えがあるのに)欲しい答えにたどり着けない場合があります。 探し方の問題、理解力の問題かも知れません。それらを助け合うのが、Q&Aサイトの役割ではないでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

> 全ての質問に回答する義務があるのでしょうか? 仕事で回答されている方ならば、別かと思いますが、そうでなければ、放置してはいけませんか? 別のどなたか親切(?)な方の回答を待つべきと思います。
もちろん回答の義務はありません。疑問はこの手の質問は適切と言えるか(より望ましい質問の1つと言えるか)であって、回答するかどうかとは独立した話です。

> ここで質問する人は英語で読み書きできないといけないのでしょうか? 確かに英語ができた方が色々と都合の良い事が多いのは事実ですが、質問者にそれを要求する必要があるかという事です。 もし、それを要求するならば、日本語サイトなんて不要かと思います。
その点とのコンフリクトをむしろ質問しています。

> 日本語で検索しても(答えがあるのに)欲しい答えにたどり着けない場合があります。 探し方の問題、理解力の問題かも知れません。それらを助け合うのが、Q&Aサイトの役割ではないでしょうか。
それも1つのお考えであると思います。
そしてまさに「考え自体をここでは集めている」と理解していただけるとありがたいです。
それらの考えのうち、どの考え方が(大まかに)コミュニティの合意になっているんでしょうか。という質問です。