# 質問のタイトルにメタな情報を付け加えるのはアリ？

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方

[スマホで息が吹きかけられたことを検知するには？　（動画あり）](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/22960/5505)

これは私が投稿した質問なんですが、質問のタイトルに（動画あり）などの言葉が含まれており、質問の内容の冒頭には[自己回答あり]と記載しています。

実際、回答にYouTubeの動画がリンクされており、自己回答も存在するのですが、このようにタイトルに（動画あり）や[自己回答あり]などのメタ情報のようなものを加えるのはこのサイトではアリなんでしょうか？

この（動画あり）のようにタイトルをしているのは理由があって、私はニュースサイトに分類されるようなブログをよく更新しているんですが、記事のタイトルに（動画あり）のように書き加えることで、動画という情報量の豊富なコンテンツがあることを知らせ、さらにブログの記事をクリックしないでも充実度の高いコンテンツを探しやすいように（動画あり）などのメタな情報をタイトルに含んでいるんです。

[自己回答あり]と記載しているほうにつきましては、自分の質問に自分で回答してしまうと自作自演をしているように個人的に感じてしまうため、慣習的にこうしています。

スタック・オーバーフローはQAサイトですが性格的にはブログにも似たところがあり、それはコンテンツとして非常に情報量が多く納得できるメッセージも記されていることも多いことです。

ですので私はスタック・オーバーフローでもブログのときのように慣習的にタイトルには（動画あり）などと記していますが
みなさんはこのようにタイトルや質問本文に質問以外のメタな情報を含めることには反対ですか？　問題無いですか？

スタック・オーバーフローのユーザー的に反対が多いと思いますが、反対の方の意見に加えて問題がないと思ったかたの率直な意見が聞いてみたいと思いました。

Comment: 自己回答あり、という記載についての話もここに含まれるのでしょうか。

Comment: @unarist  質問内容変えました。自己回答あり、のメタ情報の記載の是非も含めるようにしました。

Answer (score 6):

何よりも、**回答に関する情報を質問側に記載する**ことに違和感を抱きました。

特定の回答の内容について質問で言及されていては、「動画を含まない」「自己回答でない」回答を他の人が追加しにくくなるようにも思います。

> 動画という情報量の豊富なコンテンツがあることを知らせ、さらにブログの記事をクリックしないでも充実度の高いコンテンツを探しやすいように

個人的には動画があるかどうかは重要ではなく、動画を含めていい回答ならプラス票がたくさんつくだろうからそれでいいのでは、というぐらいの感覚です。

ただ昨今のブログを見ていると、タイトルに「動画付き」と書くことで読んでくれる人が増えるんですかね・・・だとしても、それを狙ってこのサイトでも質問のタイトルに載せるかと言われると微妙なところです。回答側にフラグを付けて、検索結果でだけタイトルやdescriptionに載せるとかできると理想的でしょうか。

> 自分の質問に自分で回答してしまうと自作自演をしているように個人的に感じてしまうため

予告として質問側に書くのはわかりますが<sup>*1</sup>、回答を投稿してあるなら回答側に書けばいいのでは？

あえて書かずとも投稿者を見ればわかることですが・・・。

<sub>*1: 回答は知ってるけど後で書くといったクイズ形式は、これはこれで過去に議論がありました。

参考 [適切な質問かの討議：クイズ形式の質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1489/8000) ・ [Prologで繰り返し処理を行う方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2190/8000)</sub>

Comment: 思わずうなる回答。目からウロコです

Answer (score 3):

若干論点がズレていると思いながら書いてますが、 スタックオーバーフローを Spolsky が設立した背景には、様々な outdatedな/意味のない 情報ばかりがネット検索でヒットするので、その状況を打開したいがために「プログラマーの役に立つ」サイトを作ったのだと記憶しています。

なので、スタックオーバーフローは、基本的に外部のリンクをたどらなくても後から来たプログラマーにとって、役に立つ内容になっていることが、推奨されていると思っています。

動画は、現状では外部サービスを利用するしかないので、リンク切れとかになった場合にはどうしようか？みたいな話があるかなーと思いました。

Comment: 表現方法はどうであれ最終的には「プログラマにとって有益な情報となる」質問であれば構わない、ハッとしましたがその通りだと思い、いま一人で頷いています

Answer (score 0):

まず、スタック・オーバーフローでは [自己回答も歓迎](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) されます。
質問した後で自分で解決することもあるでしょうから、その知識はぜひ共有してください。

タイトルへの "(動画あり)" ですが、こちらはどちらかというと本文内の該当するリンクテキストで説明されていた方がありがたいです。

また、内容によりけりですが可能であればYouTubeなどの外部サービスを使うよりも短い GIF 動画で埋め込み表示してくれた方が内容が完結していてよいのかなと。
(動画はリニアに時間を奪われるので、使うのは本当に必要な場合に絞って欲しいというのが個人的希望です)